An isomorphism between Groups of order $p^2$
Let $G$ a group of cardinality $p^2$ such that every element of $G$ is of order different than $p^2$.
Let $a,b\in G\setminus\{e\}$ such that $b\notin\langle a\rangle$. Of course the order of $a$ and $b$ is $p$.
We consider the mapping $\varphi:(Z/pZ)^2\to G, (\overline{k},\overline{\ell})\to a^kb^\ell$.
Of course we can show easily that this mapping is well-defined and homomorphism of groups.
For the surjectivity of $\varphi$ i have the following indication:
Show that $Im(\varphi)$ contain at least $p+1$ element.
If that is true, we can conclude easily that $Im(\varphi)=G$. but the question here why $Im(\varphi)$ contain at least $p+1$ element.
Thank you for your help in advance.

After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: How do I accept an answer?, Why should we accept answers?, What should I do if someone answers my question?.

are we assuming $p$ is a prime, aymen?

A group of order $p^2$, which has no element of order $p^2$ is abelian, but not cyclic. So it must be isomorphic to $C_p\times C_p$. See for example this duplicate, or this one.

Use \langle and \rangle for delimiters, not < and >.

There are false statements in the question. Let $p=4$. Let $G$ be the group of symmetries of a regular octagon, a group of order $p^2$ with no element of order $p^2$. It has elements, other than the identity, which are not of order $p$.

Note that there is a problem with your mapping $\varphi$. It will be an homomorphism provided you know that $G$ is abelian, otherwise it might not be true.
This problem asides, to answer your question, the image of $\varphi$ contains $1,a,\ldots,a^{p-1}$ and $b$ by definition. Using your assumptions on $a$ and $b$, you might be able to show that these elements are parwise distinct.

Yes of course, in this problem we proved that G is abelien by the class equation.

@aymenorton Then you should mention that in your question.
